# List custom taxonomy terms from custom field

Tags: custom-field, terms

I am trying to output a list of terms associated with a custom taxonomy for each image I am pulling from a custom field, like so:

```
$portfolio_images = get_field('portfolio_gallery');
```

Each image has standard WP fields associated with it, such as sizes, title, caption, etc. I would like to output the list of terms associated with each image from the `media_category` taxonomy.

I am using `get_the_terms` inside another variable but I think something is wrong with my `foreach` statement. Any help would be appreciated. Full code:

```
<?php

$portfolio_images = get_field('portfolio_gallery');

foreach( $portfolio_images as $portfolio_image ):

$labels = get_the_terms( $portfolio_image['ID'], 'media_category' );
?>

<li class="gallery-item" data-myorder="<?php  echo $labels;  ?>">
     <img src="<?php echo $portfolio_image['sizes']['portfolio-thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $portfolio_image['alt']; ?>" />
     <div class="mask">
            <a class="mask-link" href="<?php echo $portfolio_image['url']; ?>">
                <div class="mask-content">
                        <h4><?php echo $portfolio_image['title']; ?></h4>
                        <p><?php echo $portfolio_image['caption']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </a>
     </div>
</li>

 <?php  endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that `get_the_terms()` returns an `array` (or false or a `WP_Error`-Object), not a string.

So, assuming that you have multiple terms for images, you could use a code like this:

```
if( $labels && !is_wp_error( $labels ) ) {
    foreach( $labels as $label ) {

        $labelarray[] = $label->name;

    }
    $labelstring = join( ", ", $labelarray );
}
```

This loops through your labels, if no error. You may want to adjust the `$labelstring` to your needs, this one produces a value like `label1, label2, label3`. You could simply skip the colon, if you don't need it.

Your whole code would look like this:

```
<?php

$portfolio_images = get_field('portfolio_gallery');

foreach( $portfolio_images as $portfolio_image ):
    unset( $labelarray );
    $labels = get_the_terms( $portfolio_image['ID'], 'media_category' );
    if( $labels && !is_wp_error( $labels ) ) {
        foreach( $labels as $label ) {

            $labelarray[] = $label->name;

        }
        $labelstring = join( ", ", $labelarray );
    }

?>

    <li class="gallery-item" data-myorder="<?php  echo $labelstring;  ?>">
         <img src="<?php echo $portfolio_image['sizes']['portfolio-thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $portfolio_image['alt']; ?>" />
         <div class="mask">
                <a class="mask-link" href="<?php echo $portfolio_image['url']; ?>">
                    <div class="mask-content">
                            <h4><?php echo $portfolio_image['title']; ?></h4>
                            <p><?php echo $portfolio_image['caption']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </a>
         </div>
    </li>

<?php  endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: thank you very much that works great. I am having an issue, however, where each sequential item contains the string from the previous item. For example, here is the output:

`<li class="gallery-item" data-myorder="Identity"></li>
<li class="gallery-item" data-myorder="Identity Print"></li>
<li class="gallery-item" data-myorder="Identity Print Print Product"></li>
<li class="gallery-item" data-myorder="Identity Print Print Product Product"></li>`

Each item contains the previous items attributes...is there a problem with my syntax?

Comment: oh, right, you need to unset the `$labelarray` at the beginning of the `foreach`. I updated the code.